# Dynamically load Blazor pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

We have created a large number of Blazor applications (35+ tools).  Each tool has it's own installer, service, database, and UI.  Customers install, from our suite of tools, only those tools they need.  Unfortunately, maintaining all of these tools as separate applications creates a huge amount of code duplication (authentication, UI, settings, installers, etc.).  But merging all these tools into a single application would mean when any tool was changed, the functionality of all the tools would have to go through the QA process.  What is needed is a way to keep the code for each tool testable separately,  and provide the ability to download updates for specific tools  separately, without having to reinstall the whole application.

I don't know if it is possible to put collections of pages in their own project (resulting in a separate DLL) then dynamically download, update, and incorporate the needed DLLs into a central UI.  I would dearly love to only have  one installer, one login page, one authentication process, shared settings, etc.  Maintaining dependent services (Windows service or Linux daemon) in a separate solution would be straightforward.   By doing something like this, we could limit the scope of testing when changes are made to a single tool, while at the same time eliminate a huge amount of code duplication.

Any ideas how I could limit the scope of testing, share code, and dynamically download and update individual parts (tools) of the application?

Comment: I think .net 8 is going to be your Holy Grail, but it's not officially released until the end of the year.  Anyway, if you want to integrate many parts into a whole, you need to run at least a minimal server app.

Comment: What types of Blazor application are we talking about here? Isn't each tool just an end point.  You compile some unique classes in the end point with a lot of shared classes from libraries?  If you change the code in a library class you need to test everything with dependancies.  If you just change some endpoint code, you test just the endpoint.

Comment: Using AdditionalAssemblies in App.razor allowed me to include additional DLLs (library projects) into the main application at runtime.  These library projects include razor pages that are searched and made available to routing.  This appears to be a solution but more testing is needed.  I just hope I'm going in the right direction and there is not a better approach.